# C# Creating a text file contains the error logs

Tags: c#

I have created a text file to save the error in that created file. I have a button which, once pressed, generates an error which should be saved to the file. But if I press the button twice, it will overwrite the first error generated, because the contents of the file are overwritten. I want to generate a another separate file to save the new error. A new file should be generated for each new error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So if I click the button 100 times, you want 100 files to be created. Why on earth would you want that?

Comment: The real question is, why would U (@AshBurlaczenko) want it?  You were the user ;)

Comment: Why on earth people ask about why somebody want to do something. This site is not about reasons, it's about problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void SaveErrorMessage(string errorMessage)
{
    string errorFile = null;
    for( int x = 0; x < Int32.MaxValue; ++x )
    {
        errorFile = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "error-{0}.txt", x);
        if( !System.IO.File.Exists(errorFileTest) )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllText(errorFile, errorMessage);
}
```

This will overwrite the last file after you've had Int32.MaxValue files, but that'll take a while.

An alternative (and probably better) approach would be to simply append to the file, rather than creating a new one.

You may also want to consider using a more robust logging solution, such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Answer (score 2):

Simple use:  [FileExists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)  and then if it exists pick a new name.    Alternatively you could just append to the file.

PSUDO:

```
public string checkFileName(string fileName){
  if(File.Exists(fileName)){
    /Pick a new one
    newFileName=  fileName + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
    return checkFileName(newFileName)
   }
   return fileName
}
```

This could be the perfect link for you  [How to Open and Append a log file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to append the errors in the same file.I want to create a separate file for each of the error

Comment: Then take my first advice.  Check if the file exists, and then change the filename.

Comment: Why use recursion for this? In the (unlikely) event that the file already exists, the name just keeps getting longer this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can add time stamp in filename, in this case you would get new file each time.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating file in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as2f1fez.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to generate a unique file name for each error that occurs in your program? Probably the easiest way to accomplish this is to use the date/time when the error occured to name the file. In the function where you are writing to the file you will want to name the file like this:

```
string filename = LogPath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss") + ".err";
```

Where LogPath is the path to the folder you want to write the error files to.